# Laravel database call returning with nothing in it?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Hi i am new to Laravel and just trying to get some data out of a table in my database. I did it the same way as in the doc's but the array i get returned is always empty. It seems to connect fine and it done return an array but with nothing in it.

In my controller

```
public function run()
    {
              $results = DB::select('select * from product', array(1));

        return sizeof($results);
    }
```

All i get back is 0 and yes there is data in my database if i run the same query in phpMyAdmin i get 4 result back. Any one got any ideas on why this dose not work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work:

```
public function run()
{
    $results = DB::table('product')->get();

    return count($results);
}
```

Also, take a look at the queries section of Laravel docs: http://laravel.com/docs/queries

If you need to execute a raw query, it should be done this way:

```
$results = DB::select(DB::raw('select * from product'))->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help that link was just what i was looking for. still a little lost over why that code did not work. It would be nice if i could just cut and paste my old query over and not have to redo them.

Comment: Just edited to give you a way to execute your raw queries. But use it with care, because Laravel tries to make your queries safe against sql injection attacks.